# XPath string function over multiple results?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have a following example of HTML code. My target is to address the prices with XPath:

```
<div class="product-price">
    <div class="Price">
        <span class="value">9,99 €</span>
    </div>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="product-price">
    <div class="Price">
        <span class="value">4,99 €</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying the following XPATH expression:

```
*//div[@class="product-price"]/span[@class="value"]/text()
```

or

```
*//div[@class="product-price"]/span[@class="value"]
```

The result is:

```
9,99 €
4,99 €
```

So far, so good. Now I need to have the result ***without currency sign*** and the decimal sign needs to be a `.` instead of a `,`.

I played around with the following expression, which I have found in this forum for a similar problem:

```
*//div[@class="product-price"]/span[@class="value" 
                                    and translate(normalize-space(),"€","")]
```

But unfortunately it does not work.

Using a loop to change the values afterwards is no option in my case.

Does anybody have a smart solution for my problem?

Comment: small correction to the xpath expressions I used: "*//div[@class="Price"]/span[@class="value"]/text() or

*//div[@class="Price"]/span[@class="value"]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempted XPath isn't working as intended because `translate()` is within a predicate, which is useful for formulating the criteria for selection but not for changing the results of the selection.  To apply a function to what's selected...

For a ***single*** such selected `span` element, you can use

```
translate(//div[@class="product-price"]/span[@class="value"], ", €", ".")
```

For ***multiple*** such selected `span` elements, in **XPath 2.0** you can use

```
//div[@class="product-price"]/span[@class="value"]/translate(., ", €", ".")
```

For ***multiple*** such selected `span` elements, in **XPath 1.0** you must iterate over the results outside of XPath.

Answer (score 0):

In **Xpath 2.0**

```
for $i in //div[@class='product-price']//span[@class='value']
return translate($i, ", €", ".")
```